# Wordpress Redirecting Form Action to Home Page

Tags: redirect, homepage

Why does wordpress redirect to the home page after submitting a form? How can I make wordpress call the right page in the form action?

Comment: Add the form code to your question to make answers possible.

Comment: also.. not really a wordpress question..

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the path in the action attribute of your form, e.g.

```
<form action="/my/form/page" method="post">
...
</form>
```

If action is missing or empty it will send the form to the current page, if it is just "/" it will send it to the home page.